# How I can run Android 4.0.4 in chroot on Ubuntu 12.04 on the Pandaboard ES?

Tags: server, android, chroot, lxc

I want to run fully functional Android 4.0.4 on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation on the Pandaboard ES with the LXC containers.

Comment: This unanswered question with no comments is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Further OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and has abandoned the question. VTC as `not reproducible`.